# Silverlight 3 won't install on Windows XP embedded 2002

Tags: silverlight-3.0, embedded

Well, I tried HARD to install silverlight 3.0 on Windows XP embedded but keeps displaying that "Install Sivlerlight Logo" as if it never picks it up or installs at all ... Anyone had same problems? Any solutions?

Comment: Not programming related and should probably be on superuser.com

Comment: Or serverfault - hard to find many home users with XP Embedded licences, setting it up is more the domain of sys admins.

Comment: Welll thanks for comments, actually the XP embedded system is part of a samsung monitor which is used to display information in a slide form.
I can't see what is not related to programming if not silverlight inlcuding its deplyoment issues !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider trying to install this by copying some files around. This probably is totally unsupported, but it may work for you:

1. Install on your development machine the Silverlight Runtime
2. Copy the %programfiles%\microsoft silverlight\ ... directory structure to the XP Embedded machine
3. On the XP machine, as an Administrator, run "regsvr32 npctrl.dll"

You *might* be able to then use Silverlight content. Hope this helps.

Comment: I did what you said, but when I run "regsvr32 npctrl.dll", an error is thrown saying: 
LoadLibrary ("npctrl.dll") failed: The specified module could not be found.
Any ideas?

Comment: It is possible that some dependencies (C runtimes?) are not on the XP embedded machine.